# Why am I allowed to load an image in the non-GUI thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, invoke

Well known is that you cannot change the GUI with any other thread than the GUI thread. So a simple trick that is commonly used (which I use) is invoking:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { pictureBox1.Visible = false; });
```

I was building my program and started it, quickly noticing that I forgot to put an `PictureBox.Load(string url)` in the invoker, however no error had occurred.

So I am curious, why am I not allowed to do (in non-GUI thread):

```
pictureBox1.Visible = false; // eg.
```

But am allowed to do:

```
pictureBox1.Load(url); // url = link to image
```

Comment: Be careful with semantics here, although you call `this.Invoke` in one context, you are actually invoking in the **GUI** thread, not the non-GUI thread.

Comment: Ouch, worded that wrongly. Edited, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you load a new image, [this is what happens](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs.html#2d97bfb17a64c685) inside the `PictureBox` (this is called from the `Load` method):

```
    private void InstallNewImage(Image value,
                                 ImageInstallationType installationType)
    {
        StopAnimate();
        this.image = value;

        LayoutTransaction.DoLayoutIf(AutoSize, this, this, PropertyNames.Image); 

        Animate();
        if (installationType != ImageInstallationType.ErrorOrInitial)
        {
            AdjustSize();
        }
        this.imageInstallationType = installationType;

        Invalidate();
        CommonProperties.xClearPreferredSizeCache(this);
    }
```

So you can see that all it really does is set the image and then call `Invalidate`, which can be called from other threads.

[`Visible`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs.html#34eb26e129516529) (inherited from `Control`), which you can see here, does a lot of stuff through p/invoke and must be done on the main UI thread.

```
    protected virtual void SetVisibleCore(bool value) {
        try {
            System.Internal.HandleCollector.SuspendCollect();

            if (GetVisibleCore() != value) {
                if (!value) {
                    SelectNextIfFocused();
                }

                bool fireChange = false;

                if (GetTopLevel()) {

                    // The processing of WmShowWindow will set the visibility
                    // bit and call CreateControl()
                    //
                    if (IsHandleCreated || value) {
                            SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(new HandleRef(this, Handle), value ? ShowParams : NativeMethods.SW_HIDE);
                    }
                }
                else if (IsHandleCreated || value && parent != null && parent.Created) {

                    // We want to mark the control as visible so that CreateControl
                    // knows that we are going to be displayed... however in case
                    // an exception is thrown, we need to back the change out.
                    //
                    SetState(STATE_VISIBLE, value);
                    fireChange = true;
                    try {
                        if (value) CreateControl();
                        SafeNativeMethods.SetWindowPos(new HandleRef(window, Handle),
                                                       NativeMethods.NullHandleRef,
                                                       0, 0, 0, 0,
                                                       NativeMethods.SWP_NOSIZE
                                                       | NativeMethods.SWP_NOMOVE
                                                       | NativeMethods.SWP_NOZORDER
                                                       | NativeMethods.SWP_NOACTIVATE
                                                       | (value ? NativeMethods.SWP_SHOWWINDOW : NativeMethods.SWP_HIDEWINDOW));
                    }
                    catch {
                        SetState(STATE_VISIBLE, !value);
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                if (GetVisibleCore() != value) {
                    SetState(STATE_VISIBLE, value);
                    fireChange = true;
                }

                if (fireChange) {
                    // We do not do this in the OnPropertyChanged event for visible
                    // Lots of things could cause us to become visible, including a
                    // parent window.  We do not want to indescriminiately layout
                    // due to this, but we do want to layout if the user changed
                    // our visibility.
                    //

                    using (new LayoutTransaction(parent, this, PropertyNames.Visible)) {
                        OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                }
                UpdateRoot();
            }
            else { // value of Visible property not changed, but raw bit may have

                if (!GetState(STATE_VISIBLE) && !value && IsHandleCreated) {
                    // PERF - setting Visible=false twice can get us into this else block
                    // which makes us process WM_WINDOWPOS* messages - make sure we've already 
                    // visible=false - if not, make it so.
                     if (!SafeNativeMethods.IsWindowVisible(new HandleRef(this,this.Handle))) {
                        // we're already invisible - bail.
                        return;
                     }
                }

                SetState(STATE_VISIBLE, value);

                // If the handle is already created, we need to update the window style.
                // This situation occurs when the parent control is not currently visible,
                // but the child control has already been created.
                //
                if (IsHandleCreated) {

                    SafeNativeMethods.SetWindowPos(
                                                      new HandleRef(window, Handle), NativeMethods.NullHandleRef, 0, 0, 0, 0, NativeMethods.SWP_NOSIZE |
                                                      NativeMethods.SWP_NOMOVE | NativeMethods.SWP_NOZORDER | NativeMethods.SWP_NOACTIVATE |
                                                      (value ? NativeMethods.SWP_SHOWWINDOW : NativeMethods.SWP_HIDEWINDOW));
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            System.Internal.HandleCollector.ResumeCollect();
        }
    }
```

Just as a side-note, a lot of these "what happens under the hood" can be figured out by [browsing the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/), or creating a small application and decompiling it (I would recommend JetBrains DotPeek, or ildasm works too).

Comment: If the downvoter wouldn't mind commenting, I'd like to know what the issue was.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you do not get the "Cross-thread operation not valid" message is because the exception is thrown when [the control Handle property](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,f8a3ff8836ea5045) is accessed:

```
public IntPtr Handle {
    get {
        if (checkForIllegalCrossThreadCalls &&
            !inCrossThreadSafeCall &&
            InvokeRequired) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.IllegalCrossThreadCall,
                                                             Name));
        }

        if (!IsHandleCreated)
        {
            CreateHandle();
        }

        return HandleInternal;
    }
}
```

As you can see from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33222417/171134), `SetVisibleCore` (called by Visible) uses `Handle` several times, but `InstallNewImage` (used by `Load`) does not.  (Actually, `Invalidate` does access the Handle property, but it does so within a thread safe call scope which is fine.)